# Error Spotting : The whole of India / The whole India

Tags: exam-questions

What's the error in the  following csentence ?

> The whole India (A) mourned the sad and sudden  (b) demise of Mahatma Gandhi. (C) No error. (D)

Someone told me that part A is wrong, in his opinion the correct form is **The whole of India**
He told that the general structure is

The whole + common noun

The whole of + proper noun

since India is proper noun so *of* will come here. Is it true ?

Comment: I think your friend gave you good guidance. That said, I think "All of India" would be even better.

Comment: @J.R. A sentence can be made better in many ways and that's called a sentence improvement question but it is an error spotting question and I guess we have to spot the grammatical errors in such question so is 'the whole India' grammatically wrong ?

Comment: Yes, the whole India is wrong, but not the whole country of India. But it's heavy.

Comment: user212388 - I told you, I think your friend gave you good guidance.

Comment: But what's the reason for "The whole India" being wrong?